# How can I get the coordinates from a remote mobile phone

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I need to have the coordinates (latitude, longitude) from remote mobile phones to be in the position to present the position of the remote mobile phone using Google Geolocation.
I don't have to have a trace to be on all the time. I am happy to poll the location of the mobile phone in question, but must have the reply be in a format so that I can feed the Google Geolocation (Javascript API) with that information.
Installing an additional Javascript on the remote mobile phone with the ability listen for requests and to deliver said information is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your requirement is:

- Poll a remote mobile device (Android  or iPhone?) to get the location
- It should be **on demand**

### Possible solutions:

Here you have to initiate the mobile device to access the location data, and send it to your server. You can use HTTP to send data from mobile to your server.

You can implement this is two ways:

- **An app running in the device which constantly sends the location to your server**

  - Here, you need an app installed in the device. This must be a native application with internet connectivity.
- **Sending a request to the device through Push Notifications/SMS**

  - You can send a push notification to the device.
  - You can send an SMS to the device.
  - Upon receiving a push notification or SMS, you can start the app and get the data, and push it by initiating an HTTP request to your server.

The case of push notification, it works only with a working internet connection. In that case, SMS is the best solution.

If your app is for a particular set of users - like survey, research etc - then you can imply conditions (like internet connection/ network coverage) on your users. If you are designing for public users, then you must not push any conditions on the users.